# Setting height of textview adds padding at top

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

I am having a bit of issue while setting a layout , the problem is that the text for user's bio can vary but making it's textview height which is tvbio in below code wrap_content is adding padding at top , so effectively disturbing all the layout , here is my xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/userInfoHeadrLL"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:paddingRight="10dip"
            android:paddingTop="0dip" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/userInfoRL"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="-50dip"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:layout_width="120dp"
                    android:layout_height="120dip"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@null"
                    android:paddingRight="6dip"
                    android:src="@drawable/anonymous_user" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVAmountEarned"
                    style="@style/small_body_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="40dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="42dip"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="$0.00"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVHolder"
                    style="@style/small_body_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/TVFullName"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:paddingBottom="-5dip"
                    android:text="samjaved"
                    android:textColor="@color/blue" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVFullName"
                    style="@style/small_body_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/simpleViewAboveTable"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
                    android:text="sami"
                    android:textColor="@color/grey" />

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/simpleViewAboveTable"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/tableUserInfoFollow"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:background="@color/llgrey" />

                <TableLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tableUserInfoFollow"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="45dip"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dip"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:stretchColumns="*" >

                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="45dip" >

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textPostedCount"
                                style="@style/small_body_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="0" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvPosted"
                                style="@style/small_body_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="-8dip"
                                android:text="Posted" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textFollowersCount"
                                style="@style/small_body_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="0" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvFollower"
                                style="@style/small_body_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="-8dip"
                                android:text="Followers" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:orientation="vertical" >

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/textFollowedCount"
                                style="@style/small_body_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="0" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/tvFollowed"
                                style="@style/small_body_text"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginTop="-8dip"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Followed" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </TableRow>
                </TableLayout>

                <View
                    android:id="@+id/simpleViewBelowLayout"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tableUserInfoFollow"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:background="@color/llgrey" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TVbio"
                    style="@style/small_body_text"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="200dip"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/simpleViewBelowLayout"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/IVProfilePicture"
                    android:paddingBottom="0dip"
                    android:text="bio will go here sahsakjhdjahdjhdjhdjsahdjhahahdjhdsjhdajhdsjhdskjhakjhdskjashjkasjk" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

To solve this , i am currently checking the bio's text in code and setting height and margins accordingly , but that doesnt seem like the best way as it is showing different results on different screens, any help in this regard will be appreciated.

EDIT [image]

[image: And this is how it should show when there is text at bottom][image]
1st is the desired behaviour for no text

2nd is is how it should show when there is text at bottom

3rd is  is how it is showing currently when there is no text , note the extra space below $0.00

How to get rid of that extra space?

If to achieve that i reduce the height of textview , problem occur for larger texts as they start getting cropped.

Comment: Can you show with screenshot?

Comment: You can reduce the padding of the TextView using the attribute `paddingTop`.

Comment: @drschultz i actually dont know how much paddingtop i should set because the height of textview is varying depending on the text

Comment: @chossen-addict - It doesn't matter what the height of the TextView is. It just determines how much space is between the edge of the View and the text that's in it. If that's not your problem, then you're not having an issue with padding. You might upload a screenshot so we can actually see what the problem is.

Comment: @drschultz screenshots added.

Comment: @YuvaRaj screenshots added

Comment: Is the 3rd screenshot what it looks like when the TVbio TextView `layout_height` is set to `wrap_content`?

Comment: no , the 3rd screenshot is when it is set to 200dip , if i set it to wrap_content , longer texts start getting cropped

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92222/discussion-between-chossen-addict-and-drschultz).

Answer (score 0):

I think that setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` is definitely the way to go for your TVbio TextView. You certainly want the size of the View to size according to the amount of varied text you will receive. So I think that part is right.

But if your text is getting cut off when using that attribute, I would try setting `android:layout_gravity="fill"`. This attribute tells the parent how the child view should be positioned inside the container. I would start with trying `fill` and if that doesn't work, you can experiment with some of the other ones. You can find a list of [all possible settings here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#layout_gravity).

Comment: Also, you could try adding a couple of `\n` characters to the end of the text to try to force the View to size a little bigger than your actual text content.